# Lost all Maven options in SpringSource STS

Tags: eclipse, maven

I seem to have lost all maven options in SpringSource STS tools version 3.2.0.

I can't add Maven nature to the project, as my only options are to covert to Javascript or Plug in Project.  No Maven options are visible in Window Preferences...and although I can see in my .plugins folder, plugins related to m2e, when I do "about Spring Tool Suite", the m2e icon is not there any more.  I tried to reinstall m2e from the eclipse market place but it hasn't helped.

As I can see the plugins in my project .metadata/.plugins:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.core
org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui
org.eclipse.m2e.core.jdt
```

my .project file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>AdminDirect</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.rebelXmlBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
        <nature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</nature>
        <nature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</nature>
        <nature>org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.jrebelNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

I am a bit new to all this, but I have been building using m2e for 6 months on this project, and it just vanished.  I can still build via mvn command line.